# Axiom Regularity in $L$ Without $WF$

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I know, how I can prove that Axiom regularity holds in $L$ with $WF$, so axiom regularity holds in every transitive subset $WF$.

But how can I prove, that axiom regularity holds in $L$ without using $WF$?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question - are you asking why $L^V$ satisfies regularity even when $V$ is illfounded?

Comment: No, so i need prove that L is model ZF and i dont wanna define WF.

Comment: But I don't see how WF enters into it at all - *every* set in a model of ZF appears well-founded in that model, that is, $WF^V=V$ whenever $V\models ZF$. So I don't see what it's doing here. And indeed, this is why it's trivial that $L$ satisfies regularity if $V$ is well-founded. It sounds like you're asking why $L$ satisfies ZF without using the assumption that $V$ is actually well-founded, just that it satisfies regularity (that is, $V$ *thinks* that it is well-founded).

Comment: Yes,I need prove that L satisfies axiom regularity.

Comment: I understand that - as I said in my comment, I don't understand what role WF plays. What is the proof of regularity in L that you want to *avoid*?

Comment: Axiom Foundation is true in M \subset WF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First prove that the axiom of regularity is equivalent to the existence of *a* rank function. Namely, a function $r$ from sets to ordinals such that when $x\in y$ it follows that $r(x) < r(y)$.

Then use the definition of $L$ to come up with such a rank function.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking for; I think you're asking for a proof which doesn't use the assumption that $V$ is actually well-founded.

The proof amounts to the following:

> If $M\models ZF$ and $X$ is a definable transitive subclass of $M$, then $(X, \in^M\upharpoonright X)$ satisfies regularity.

Let $x\in X$. By regularity in $M$, there is some $y\in x$ with $y\cap x=\emptyset$; by transitivity of $X$, $y\in X$. So $X\models \exists a(a\in x, a\cap x=\emptyset)$.

Comment: I suspect that my answer was my in line of the spirit of the question. But we'll have to wait for the OP to confirm...

Comment: I think that our suspicions are confirmed at this point... :)